# C recv() not reading in buffer

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I'm totally new to network programming. So I'm working on a program that passes something like this to the socket, and try to read the content in HTML (I think it's in HTML, someone correct me on this):

```
GET infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/focs.html HTTP/1.1\r\n 
Host: www.google.com\r\n 
\r\n
```

`infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/focs.html` is the site I'm trying to read.

So I store that GET message up there in a string, then use the send() method to send the request to the server. I checked errno and it returns `Success`.

Then I use recv() to read the content and store it in a buffer. I did a bit of googling and found that buffer[6000] is like a standard.

However, my program takes forever to run recv(). errno returns `Success`, but when I try to print buffer, it's just a blank line.

```
int open_clientfd(char *hostname, int port)
{
   int clientfd;
   struct hostent *hp;
   struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;

   if ((clientfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
      return -1; /* Check errno for cause of error */

   /* Fill in the server's IP address and port */
   if ((hp = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL)
      return -2; /* Check h_errno for cause of error */
   bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
   serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   bcopy((char *)hp->h_addr_list[0],
         (char
          *)&serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         hp->h_length);
   serveraddr.sin_port = htons(port);

   /* Establish a connection with
    * the server */
   if (connect(clientfd, (SA *)
            &serveraddr,
            sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0)
      return -1;
   return clientfd;
}

void sendRequest(int clientfd, char request[128]) {
   char buffer[6000];
   int byteSent, byteRead;

   // send request
   byteSent = send(clientfd, request, sizeof(request), 0);
   fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));

   // read
   byteRead = recv(clientfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
   fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));

   fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int clientfd, port;
   char *host, *fileURL;

   rio_t rio;

   host = argv[1];
   fileURL = argv[2];

   port = atoi(argv[3]);

   clientfd = open_clientfd(host, port);

   // set up request string
   char request[128]; 

   // ....

   // now request stores the string above

   sendRequest(clientfd, request);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The usual suspects: treating a buffer as a null-terminated char array when is is not guaranteed to be so.  Failing to correctly handle the result returned by recv().

Comment: For one, `sizeof(request)` in your `send` call in `sendRequest` isn't doing what you think it is. The `request` variable is a pointer via conversion when passed as a parameter, not the array from the caller, and thus `sizeof` will give you exactly what you asked for: the size of a pointer. And minor, but it still shouldn't happen,  there is no `Open_clientfd`, but there is an `open_clientfd`.

Comment: ..and if you are thinking of reaching for strlen() in response to @WhozCraig comments, please think again.  Pass the number of bytes that you wish to send as a separate parameter.

Comment: Check what is happening with wireshark.  Use your debugger to check the value of byteRead and what is in the buffer after recv() returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setup for your request is wrong. First, you're sending data equivalent to the size of a *pointer*, not the request buffer. Second, the request GET should not include the site name; that is used for establishing the connection.

A stripped down version of your setup and invoke that works is presented below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>

int open_clientfd(char *hostname, int port)
{
    int clientfd;
    struct hostent *hp;
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;

    if ((clientfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        return -1; /* Check errno for cause of error */

    /* Fill in the server's IP address and port */
    if ((hp = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL)
        return -2; /* Check h_errno for cause of error */
    bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)hp->h_addr_list[0],
          (char *)&serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr,
          hp->h_length);
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    /* Establish a connection with the server */
    if (connect(clientfd, (const struct sockaddr*)
                &serveraddr,
                sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0)
        return -1;
    return clientfd;
}

void sendRequest(int clientfd, char request[], size_t rlen)
{
    ssize_t byteSent, byteRead;

    // send request
    byteSent = send(clientfd, request, rlen, 0);
    if (byteSent < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    // read response
    do
    {
        char buffer[1024];
        byteRead = recv(clientfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, 0);
        if (byteRead < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
            return;
        }

        buffer[byteRead] = 0;
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", buffer);

    } while (byteRead > 0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int clientfd = open_clientfd("infolab.stanford.edu", 80);
    if (clientfd < 0)
    {
        perror(NULL);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // set up request string
    char request[] = "GET /~ullman/focs.html HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                     "Host: www.google.com\r\n"
                     "\r\n";

    // now request stores the string above
    sendRequest(clientfd, request, sizeof(request)-1);
    close(clientfd);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 08 Aug 2015 16:24:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Wed, 17 Mar 2010 21:53:56 GMT
ETag: "3448c4fe-f93-269bc500"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 3987
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<TITLE>Aho/Ullman Foundations of Computer Science</TITLE>

<BODY BGCOLOR = "E0F7F0">

<CENTER><TABLE>
<TR><TD><IMG SRC = "gifs/focs.gif"></td>
<TD ALIGN = MIDDLE><FONT SIZE = 6>Foundations of Computer
Science</font></td></tr>
<TR></tr>
</TABLE></CENTER>
<P>
This book has been taken out of print by W. H. Freeman.
You are welcome to use it if you like.
We believed in 1992 it was the way to introduce theory in
Computer Science, and we believe that today.
<P>
<CENTER>--- Al Aho and Jeff Ullman</center>
<P>
<H3>Index</H3>
<P>
<A href="#pdfs">The Book</a> |
<A href="#supp">Materials</a> |
<A href="#grad">Gradiance</a> |
<A href="#errata">Errata</a>

<A name="pdfs"></a>
<H3>PDF's of the Book</H3>
<P>
<UL>
<LI><A href="focs/preface.pdf">Preface</a>
<LI><A href="focs/toc.pdf">Table of Contents</a>
<LI><A href="focs/ch01.pdf">Chapter 1</a> Computer Science: The
Mechanization of Abstraction
<LI><A href="focs/ch02.pdf">Chapter 2</a> Iteration, Induction, and
Recursion
<LI><A href="focs/ch03.pdf">Chapter 3</a> The Running Time of Programs
<LI><A href="focs/ch04.pdf">Chapter 4</a> Combinatorics and Probability
<LI><A href="focs/ch05.pdf">Chapter 5</a> The Tree Data Model
<LI><A href="focs/ch06.pdf">Chapter 6</a> The List Data Model
<LI><A href="focs/ch07.pdf">Chapter 7</a> The Set Data Model
<LI><A href="focs/ch08.pdf">Chapter 8</a> The Relational Data Model
<LI><A href="focs/ch09.pdf">Chapter 9</a> The Graph Data Model
<LI><A href="focs/ch10.pdf">Chapter 10</a> Patterns, Automata, and
Regular Expressions
<LI><A href="focs/ch11.pdf">Chapter 11</a> Recursive Description of
Patterns
<LI><A href="focs/ch12.pdf">Chapter 12</a> Propositional Logic
<LI><A href="focs/ch13.pdf">Chapter 13</a> Using Logic to Design
Computer Components
<LI><A href="focs/ch14.pdf">Chapter 14</a> Predicate Logic
<LI><A href="focs/index.pdf">Index</a>
</ul>

<A name="supp"></a>
<H3>Supplementary Materials</H3>
<P>
<UL>
<LI><A HREF = "pub/sols-fcsc-new.ps">Solutions to Selected Exercises</a>
<LI><A HREF = "fcs-exams.html">A Selection of Exams and Projects</A>
<LI><A HREF = "fcsc-notes.html">Jeff Ullman's Lecture Notes</A>
(ancient)
<LI><A HREF = "fcsc-figures.html">The Programs Appearing in the Book</a>
</ul>

<A name="grad"></a>
<H3>Gradiance Package Available</H3>

<P>
<A href="http://www.gradiance.com">Gradiance</a>
is offering a free trial of its automated homeworks for the topics
covered by this book.  These homeworks are designed as a teaching aid
rather than an assessment tool.  Students get advice when they make a
mistake and are encouraged to try working on the same problem(s) until
they get them right.  If you would like to try the system gratis for
your class, make yourself an account at <A
href="http://www.gradiance.com/services"><TT>www.gradiance.com/services</tt></a>.
Then, send email to sup port @grad iance .com (ignore the blanks in that
email address, of course) telling us your login and that you would like
to try the discrete-math product.  You can find manuals for
instructors, students, and question-authors at <A
href="http://www.gradiance.com/info.html"><TT>www.gradiance.com/info.html</tt></a>.
<P>
<B>Special offer for students</b>:  Until June 30, 2009, we have made use of the
Gradiance materials available for students whose instructors are not using
the system.  Make yourself an account on
<A href="http://www.gradiance.com/services"><TT>www.gradiance.com/services</tt></a>,
and then sign up for the class 8CD5ED01.  You will be able to work 31 selected
homeworks, and will get advice when you make an error.  The only difference is that
we cannot reveal solutions, because these assignments are open indefinitely.

<A name="errata"></a>
<H3>Errata Sheet</H3>

We are going to try to maintain errata.  Please see
<A href="focs/errata.html">The Errata Sheet</a>.
If you find an unreported error, please send email to ullman
at gmail dot com.

<!-- -->
<script src="http://tags.stanford.edu/tags.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- -->

</BODY>
```

Comment: Thanks!
Can you explain why it must be sizeof(request)  - 1 ?

Comment: @PTN `sizeof(request)` in `main()` includes the terminating nullchar, which we *do not* want to send.